# How to exit from the loop when user clicks X button on userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code below to edit every row one by one on userform interface:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set MyRange = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In MyRange            
        cell.Select

        'Build form            
        MyForm.Title.Caption = cell.Offset(0, 2)

        If cell.Offset(0, 2) = 1 Then
            MyForm.Checked.Value = True
        Else
            MyForm.Checked.Value = False
        End If

        'Show form
        MyForm.Show  
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I have thousand of rows and I need to give user a some break!

I want this process to pause if user clicks X button, but I couldn't find a way to exit from the loop.

My userform code is like below:

```
Private Sub Checked_Click()
    If MyForm.Checked.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    End If 
End Sub


Private Sub DoneButton_Click()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
    Unload MyForm 
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
       MsgBox "paused"
    End If
End Sub
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish?**

I need to stop for each loop at first block of code when users click X button to close the userform. But I don't know how to listen if `UserForm_QueryClose` called to exit loop from first block of code.

Comment: @Rawrplus is correct, how about filling in a nearby column with "Completed" and have the form loop to find where the user left off on open?

Comment: @StevenCarlson, current code does it, the problem is if users exit from user form using X button, userform will be promt again for the next row.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't think this is possible, given [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) doesn't support multi-threading.

If you really insist on asking the user whether to pause, it would be better to simply ask an `If` conditional during the run-time.

eg.

```
For i = 1 to myRange.Cells.Count

 ' your code here...

 If i = myRange.Cells.Count / 2 Then
    If MsgBox("Continue to the for loop?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
       UnLoad MyForm
       Exit For
    End If
 End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add DoEvents which will check for a user interaction.  However, simply closing the form will not stop the code from running so you will need to add another controller.

For example

```
Option Explicit
Private stopCode As Boolean
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    stopCode = False
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Debug.Print i
        DoEvents
        If stopCode = True Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to stop", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Cancel = True
    stopCode = True
End Sub
```

When the user closes the form they will be asked if they want to stop the code.  If they say yes it closes the form but the **stopCode** 'controller' also makes sure the running code is stopped.